# null exception with lists in c#

Tags: c#, list, properties, automatic-properties

hey i am trying to work with a generic list in C# and for some reason after allocating memory for the list i am getting unhandeledNullException.

```
 //edit
```

i found out what was my problem i did not use the properties currectly.
if lets say GeoInfo is a private member of my class, how do i do properties to it,
i tried :

```
 private List<GeoInfo> GEOINFOS { get; set; } // edit i forgot to change it back 
// but i want to have my geoinfos private and my properties public
```

thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Is that `UnhandledException` or `ArgumentNullException` - please clarify. Also, there is nothing inherently wrong with that code *by itself* - I think you are going to have to add more context; ideally a reproducible example.

Comment: That line by itself looks fine. Can you post more code? It's probably something else that's causing it.

Comment: Please post a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. It's likely to be something simple, but we can't tell from just that line.

Comment: Why a public setter for a List? And your screaming caps name for a propery is unusual too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made the properties private. If you want them to be public try:

```
public List<GeoInfo> GeoInfos { get; set; }
```

The auto-implemented value that is stored locally in the object will be private; but the properties themselves are public.

Because what you are declaring there are the property accessors.

If you want to write everything explicitly, you could do it the old pre 3.0 way

```
private List<GeoInfo> geoInfos = new List<GeoInfo>;
public List<GeoInfo> GeoInfos {
  get { return geoInfos; }
  set { geoInfos = value; }
}
```

This still **relies on geoInfos being initialized somewhere** (like the constructor) -- or `nullPointerException` will return.

You could do lazy-evaluation on it right in the getter:

```
private List<GeoInfo> geoInfos = new List<GeoInfo>;
public List<GeoInfo> GeoInfos {
  get { if (geoInfos == null) {
          geoInfos = new List<GeoInfo>;
        } 
        return geoInfos; 
      }
  set { geoInfos = value; }
}
```

This ensures that you don't have to specify a call in the constructor, and you don't have to worry about the execution sequence setting the element explicitly prior to getting it.

But if you use the auto-generated-properties, you will have to explicitly set the reference at some point. AS suggested elsewhere, the best bet is the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a property to be private, use

```
private List<GeoInfo> GEOINFOS { get; set; }
```

However, there's not a lot of reason to use an auto property for a private member variable (and don't forget to initialize that list as well).  If you want validation fine, but you're just using that property as a private variable.

Your null reference issue probably comes from not initializing the underlying property variable.  That does not get done automatically, so

```
public MyClass()
{
    GEOINFOS = new List<GeoInfo>();
}
```

One more thing:  your naming convension for a property is odd for C#.  How about keeping things consistent and sing GeoInfos?

Comment: For a fully private auto-property you'd use `private List<GeoInfo> GeoInfos { get; set; }`.

Comment: Like @Luke says, a public property with private getter+setter won't fly. But +1 for the naming suggestion

Comment: i dont want my properties to be private i want them to be public

Comment: I did a triple-take on that public keyword.  No.  I *do* see a reason for a private auto property.  Same reasoning applies, just less compelling.

Comment: Err... sorry, not sure what I was thinking on that one.  I was in a rush.  Fixed.  It makes no sense to have public properties with private getter/setters.  @Hans: Not sure what your reasoning would be for a private auto property.  If you decide that you want validation later on the change is as simple as changing the name of the private field.  I mean, it doesn't hurt, but it is pointless.

Comment: Rescued, good move.  Not so sure what this has to do with validation.  The benefit of an *public* auto property is clear, refactor without doing much harm.  That doesn't really stop at the class level, imagine a class that has a 1000 lines of code.  Move that LOC level down until you find a reason to not use a private property.  To each their own.

Comment: Yes, definitely true for a public interface.  Implementation details like this are easily refactored, which is where I was coming from.